# What is the function of 而 and 為咗 in 我哋為咗決定去邊度度蜜月而閙交 in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, nuance

> 我哋為咗決定去邊度度蜜月而閙交.

In this sentence, I understand that the meaning is “we got into an argument when deciding where to go for a honeymoon.”

What is the function of 而 and 為咗？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**為咗** A **而** B] = [ to B **for** A]. It is a two parts function word for  "**for** "

[(**為咗**) cause (**而**) verb]  =  [verb (**for**) cause]

Example :

"(**為咗**)钱(**而**)工作" =  "work (**for**) money"

> [我哋(**為咗**)決定去邊度度蜜月(**而**)閙交] =  [we (*to*) quarrel (**for**) deciding where to go to have honeymoon]

In English, we have to omit "to" before the verb if there's a subject in the sentence , e.g. "to work for money" -->  "I work for money". but we don't omit "而" in "我**為咗**钱**而**工作" in Chinese, because [**為咗** cause **而** verb] is a set structure.